# How to call a common function after both of the js files are loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I want to show markers on map in the form of clusters and for that purpose I am using "markercluster.js" and google maps v3 library. But the problem here is that to show markers on the map both the files should be loaded completely. One solution is that I load atleast one of the file synchronously but I want to load both the files using async and defer. Is there any way I can achieve both the things. Currently I am loading files in this way but when googleapi is loaded before markercluster then it start showing markerCluster as undefined inside initialize function.

```
<script async defer src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>   
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initialize"> </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable and onload events.

```
<script async defer src="js/markerclusterer.js" onload="init()"></script>   
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3" onload="init()"></script>
```

Then your function could look like this:

```
var g_file_loaded = 0;

function init()
{
    g_file_loaded++;

    if (g_file_loaded === 2)
    {
        // your initialize function here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working file. If you had worked with gplus login these please try to answer my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211396/whats-the-difference-between-gapi-auth-signin-and-gapi-auth-authorize-in-gplus